# Windows use own title bars and global title bar is still here

Tags: unity, gnome, window, titlebar

Firstly, sorry for my english, if it is making it difficult to understand the problem. I don't how but some days ago, my windows started to show own title bars while global title bar is still standing there.
And it is frustrating, I love the global title bar and I want it only. How can I reverse this, and what may caused it?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and only Unity.

[image: It looks like this]

Comment: Have you recently added a PPA?

Comment: Yeah, I don't remember  exactly why but I've added gnome3team.

Comment: You'll need to remove whatever PPAs you added and remove the packages they installed.

Comment: I've removed it and then rebooted but nothing changed.

Comment: By the way, I remembered why I added it, I was trying to install corebird, I removed it too, but everything's same.

Comment: If by "remove" you mean you disable them, you did not remove anything.

Comment: Sorry, as you can guess, I'm kinda new to ubuntu. I removed them from synaptic package manager, wouldn't it be enough?

Comment: What repositories did you specifically added besides gnome3team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove both the PPA And the packages it may have installed, you first need [PPA-purge](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/remove-ppa-repositories-via-command.html) in order to do so, to install PPA-purge:

> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

After you installed it, you'll need to get the PPA name(s) you added and run:

> sudo ppa-purge ppa/name

In the case of ["Gnome3 Team"](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3) PPA, it would be like this:

> sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

Comment: I did it now and rebooted again, but sadly, nothing changed.  I tried to find any other irrelevant ppas and only ubuntu-x-swat is something I don't know. And it seems like it is freshly added.

Comment: Did you enable back the Gnome3 Team PPA to correctly remove it?

Comment: Yeap, still same.

Comment: Okay, I found one more ppa related to gnome3 (gnome3 staging) and I purged it. Now my terminal titlebar is back to normal, but nautilus is still same.

Comment: You may need to stop Nautilus or just log out.

Comment: Okay, just to be sure I readded that ppa and gnome3-staging and then purged them one by one. Then I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop (because when I purged the latter, nautilus went nuts) and finally I rebooted and everything's back to normal. Thanks for your help. :)